# How can I view my remote desktop that is behind a NAT router

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, ubuntu-10.04

I have my ubuntu machine at work and I'd like to use remote desktop to work from home. However the remote machine is on a behind a NAT router and not directly connected to the internet.

I am able to remotely connect through ssh to a server, from which I then ssh to my remote machine. This has been beneficial, however I am currently working on a GUI application so just the command line doesn't work so well. Any ideas?

I have tried using ssh with the -X flag on both sessions, but this doesn't work.
I am trying to connect from Windows Vista through a Mac server (isn't it a great setup?).

Answer (score 1):

You say remote desktop and tag your question ubuntu-10.04. So I assume you are using VNC and the development machine is ubuntu.

On your Vista machine do the equivalent of `ssh -L 5910:ubuntu_ip:5900 mac_ip` (following those [putty screenshots](http://www.cs.uu.nl/technical/services/ssh/putty/puttyfw.html): hostname=mac_ip, source port=5910, destination=ubuntu_ip)

Point your VNC client to `localhost:10`

Answer (score 0):

Using your SSH server as a proxy would probably enable you to do what you're looking for:

http://www.knightwise.com/knightcast-podcast/584

Answer (score -1):

Run X server on your Windows Vista. Maybe cygwin X or xming will help. Then in the Linux machine do the following:

```
export DISPLAY=yourip:0.0
```

then do a

```
xhost +yourip
```

then do

```
yourguiapplication &
```

It will launch the GUI application, which will appear on your Windows desktop. For launching firefox on my Windows desktop from the Linux machine I would do the above line as follows:

```
$firefox &
```

Here is a sample of the above as in my desktop
I would launch xming . Once it is in my windows desktop tray. I would launch putty and enable x11 forwarding check box on putty and launch the terminal.
Then

```
export DISPLAY=192.168.1.11:0.0
xhost +192.168.1.11
firefox &
```

That's it.

You can see the gtk interfaced firefox in you Windows desktop. If you want to do remote desktop to a Linux machine try to read about xdcmp and it can done with xming or cygwin X.

Comment: fast solution but insecure

Comment: This won't work over internet and NAT cause you'll need your public IP and the you'll have to tell the router to forward to your destination machine. No?